# Show Cyrillic letters in GUI

Tags: windows, foobar2000

My default installation `foobar2000` player now shows Cyrillic characters.

I tried most of system fonts, but no result.

[image]

How to fix it?

UPD.:

Files in IE also contains bad characters:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the file's meta data are correct? Have a look on one of the files with right-click > Properties inside File Explorer.

Comment: I have updated question body with IE view

Comment: Well then the problem is not on **foobar2000** - i would suggest to use [mp3tag](https://www.mp3tag.de/en/) and renew the metas with online database lookup

Answer (score 1):

1. First use some text editor and type in some Cyrillic characters. Is it showing up correctly? If yes, find what that font is and use it in foobar.
2. If the Cyrillic characters are not showing up correctly there, then google for 'free Cyrillic fonts', download them, extract them if they are zipped, and then drop it into the windows fonts directory.

%windir%\fonts

Now select this new font inside that text editor and see if Cyrillic is ok.

If ok, use it inside foobar too.